# Django - DatabaseError: No such table

Tags: python, database, django, django-models

I defined two models:

```
class Server(models.Model):
    owners = models.ManyToManyField('Person')

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

admin.site.register(Server)
admin.site.register(Person)
```

After that I even checked the sql, just for fun:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "servers_server_owners" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "server_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "person_id" integer NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE ("server_id", "person_id")
)
;
CREATE TABLE "servers_server" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    "port" integer unsigned NOT NULL,
    "state" integer NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "servers_person" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
;
COMMIT;
```

There it even says `CREATE TABLE "servers_server_owners"`

I ran `syncdb` to install the new models to the database. I went to the admin-interface to define some objects to play with, but I got the following error:

```
DatabaseError at /admin/servers/server/1/  
no such table: servers_server_owners
```

I shutdown the dev-server, ran `syncdb` again, started the server: Still same problem. Why can't it find, the table, even though it just told me it created id?

Comment: Either you have missing information in the above, or your example is wrong. The default intermediate table should be "servers_server_person" unless you defined the intermediate table using "through"

Comment: @James I have not used `through`, and I also thought about the same thing when I saw the sql. It seems to be picking up the name of the property

Comment: @varesa: The correct way to answer your own question on SO is to post it as an answer and accept it, not edit your original question. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @cha0site Yes, I know and already tried. There only happens to a 8 hour delay before people under 100 reputation can answer their own questions. I only edited to save others who view this question the trouble trying to answer to this, until I can post the answer. Six hours to go.

Comment: `python manage.py migrate` solve the issue for me

Comment: @Arefe Yeah, that is the way to go nowdays. Migrate did not exis four years ago so you had to use external tools like South mentioned below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually the problem was that the table never got created. Since I am fairly new with django, I did not know that `./manage.py syncdb` does not update existing models, but only creates the ones that do not exist.

Because the model 'Server' existed before I added the other model, and it was already in the db, 'syncdb' did not actually create the new tables.

Comment: So how *do* you create new tables?

Comment: @Imray There are few ways, the simplest being delete and recreate the database. A more sophisticated way is to use a "migration tool". Around the time I asked the question you had to use an external tool like South, but I think a similar tool is built into django. See `droidballoon`'s answer for the older solution and `Michael`'s answer for the new one

Answer (score 9):

As a tip for the future, look into [South](http://south.aeracode.org/), a very useful utility for applying your model changes to the database without having to create a new database each time you've changed the model(s).

With it you can easily: `python manage.py migrate app_name` and South will write your model changes.
The [documentation](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.6/index.html) is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

I meet the same problem today and fix it.
I think you miss some command in tutorial 1. 
just do follow:

```
./python manage.py makemigrations polls
python manage.py sql polls
./python manage.py syncdb
```

then fix it and gain the table polls and you can see the table created.
you should read the `manage.py makemigrations` command.

Comment: That might be the fix now, however it did not exist when I made the question.

From the official docs: "Prior to version 1.7, Django only supported adding new models to the database; it was not possible to alter or remove existing models via the syncdb command (the predecessor to migrate).

Third-party tools, most notably South, provided support for these additional types of change, but it was considered important enough that support was brought into core Django."

I can't find the release date of 1.7, but it is probably at least a year after this was asked.

Answer (score 2):

for django 1.9, this is what i did and it solved the issue.

> > python manage.py makemigrations app_name
> >
> > python manage.py migrate

Answer (score 0):

1. use "manage.py help" to check the command
2. if you find migrate and makemigration, it means your python has updated

step 1:

```
python manage.py makemigration
```

result 1:

```
Migrations for 'mainsite':
mainsite\migrations\0001_initial.py
- Create model Post
```

step 2:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

result 2:

```
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, mainsite, sessions
Running migrations:
Applying mainsite.0001_initial... OK
```

finally, runserver. Done