# django no such table:

Tags: django, django-south

I have models in Django set up as below.

```
class Pupil(models.Model):
    forename = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    dateofbirth = models.DateField()
    year = models.IntegerField()
    class_group = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    assignments = models.ManyToManyField('Assignment', verbose_name='related assignments')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.forename, self.surname)

class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField('Teacher', verbose_name='related teachers')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Teacher(models.Model):
    forename = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.forename, self.surname)

class Assignment(models.Model):
    assignment_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date_assigned = models.DateField()
    date_submitted = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.assignment_name
```

When I attempt to add a pupil and attach an assignment to the pupil in the admin, I get a database error -

```
no such table: homework_pupil_assignments
```

after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077721/django-databaseerror-no-such-table) I realised this could be due to django not updating changes to my models as when I do `manage.py sqlall homework`

I see the following:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "homework_pupil_assignments" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "pupil_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "assignment_id" integer NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE ("pupil_id", "assignment_id")
)
;
CREATE TABLE "homework_pupil" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "forename" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "surname" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "dateofbirth" date NOT NULL,
    "year" integer NOT NULL,
    "class_group" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "email" varchar(75) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "homework_subject_teachers" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "subject_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "teacher_id" integer NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE ("subject_id", "teacher_id")
)
;
CREATE TABLE "homework_subject" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "level" varchar(30) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "homework_teacher" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "forename" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "surname" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "email" varchar(75) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "homework_assignment" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "assignment_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "date_assigned" date NOT NULL,
    "date_submitted" date NOT NULL
)
;
COMMIT;
```

I then installed South, following the directions to get up and running with an existing app, in the hope of successfully syncing these tables. No joy.

Can anyone suggest how I can get the database (sqlite3) to reflect the models or point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you do a `convert_to_south app_name` before you did `schemamigration` ?

Comment: Yup. I'm also concerned that if the tables were not synced properly before the integration of South, it'll cause a problem.

Comment: check in the south_migrationhistory table, and see if this migration is executed or not

Comment: You should back out your changes to the point where they match what the database looks like, then do the schemamigration --initial. At that point, you should add your changes back in, do another schemamigration --auto and then a migrate

Comment: how do I find the migrationhistory table?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

## Updated answer for Django migrations without `south` plugin:

Like [T.T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6666653/t-t) suggested in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39030714/320104), my previous answer was for `south` migration plugin, when Django hasn't any schema migration features.
Now (works in Django 1.9+):

**[T.T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6666653/t-t) [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39030714/320104):**

> You can try this!
>
> ```
> python manage.py makemigrations
>
> python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
> ```

---

### Outdated for `south` migrations plugin

> As I can see you done it all in wrong order, to fix it up your should
>   complete this checklist (I assume you can't delete sqlite3 database
>   file to start over):
>
> 1. Grab any SQLite GUI tool (i.e. http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/)
> 2. Change your model definition to match database definition (best approach is to comment new fields)
> 3. Delete `migrations` folder in your model
> 4. Delete rows in `south_migrationhistory` table where `app_name` match your application name (probably `homework`)
> 5. Invoke: `./manage.py schemamigration <app_name> --initial`
> 6. Create tables by `./manage.py migrate <app_name> --fake` (`--fake` will skip SQL execute because table already exists in your database)
> 7. Make changes to your app's model
> 8. Invoke `./manage.py schemamigration <app_name> --auto`
> 9. Then apply changes to database: `./manage.py migrate <app_name>`
>
> Steps 7,8,9 repeat whenever your model needs any changes.

Comment: I have dropped all the tables from the shell. I then sync'd and migrated and it seems to have worked.

Comment: This does not work in Django 1.8.7 as schemamigration is no longer defined as a subcommand for manage.py

Answer (score 97):

You can try this!

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

I have the same problem with Django 1.9 and 1.10. This code works!

Answer (score 13):

If you are using latest version of django 2.x or 1.11.x  then you have to first create migrations ,

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

After that you just have to run migrate command for syncing database .

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

These will sync your database and python models and also second command will print all sql behind it.

Comment: `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb` was also working for me with django `3.0`

Answer (score 4):

. first step delete db.sqlite3 file
. go to terminal and run commands:

- `python manage.py makemigrations`
- `python manage.py migrate`
- `python manage.py createsuperuser`
- `python manage.py runserver`
  . go to admin page
  every thing ok now.

Comment: This was what fixed it for me. I had to delete the db.sqlite3 file first. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I think maybe you can try

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Even **sqlite3** need `syncdb`

sencondly, you can check your sql file name

it should look like **xxx.s3db**

Answer (score 3):

One way to sync your database to your django models is to delete your database file and run makemigrations and migrate commands again. This will reflect your django models structure to your database from scratch. Although, make sure to backup your database file before deleting in case you need your records.

This solution worked for me since I wasn't much bothered about the data and just wanted my db and models structure to sync up.

Answer (score 2):

`sqlall` just prints the SQL, it doesn't execute it. `syncdb` will create tables that aren't already created, but it won't modify existing tables.

Comment: Actually syncdb is no longer supported in the newer versions of Django and therefore this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
(1) delete -> db.sqlite3
(2) your App -> migrations directory-> delete all 001_initial.py and others but dont delete __init__.py

(3) open terminal -> 
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: This works, but be aware that it will delete your database!

Answer (score -1):

First run: `python manage.py makemigrations` 
Second run: `python manage.py migrate`