# Django Model.objects.all() returns unexpected empty QuerySet

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I have some problem while trying to use a MySQL database with Django. The database contains a table named `items`. This database is imported from a development system to a production system. This database is the second database in addition to an existing SQLite databased used by other teams. There had been an error message about `no such table`, but I was able to solve it with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784835/django-no-such-table). I then assume that there are no migration errors.

The MySQL database works fine in the development system (tested using `python manage.py shell`), but it doesn't work in the production system (tested the same way.)

I tested the import with:

```
$ python manage.py shell    

>> from project.models import Item

>> Item.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

I created the `models.py` file with:

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

I verified that the database and the table `items` actually contains records. (Although some fields are stored as unicode text, if that makes any difference to the situation.)

Here is part of the `project/settings.py` file:

```
...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'new_project': {
        'NAME': 'new_project',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'xxxxxxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxx',
    }
}
...
```

Here is part of the generated `app/models.py`:

```
...
class Item(models.Model):
    itemid = models.AutoField(db_column='ItemID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    kind = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'items'
...
```

I am using `Django 2.0.2` with `Python 3.6.3`.

Comment: Is your DB configuration correct to MYSQL?

Comment: It should give you at least `<QuerySet [<Item: Item object>]>` for the entries if you haven't defined a `__str__` method; can you simple try `x = Item("fields")` `x.save()` and then `Item.objects.all()` in `python manage.py shell`

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge I have added the details of my `project/settings.py` file

Comment: try to route your DBs, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: @IşıkKaplan I have executed your code; `Item.objects.all()` shows that there is one Item object in the resulting QuerySet. However, when I go to look at the database via MySQL CLI, the new item could not be found.

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Routing my DBs solved the problem! Please make it into an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @krismath Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has support for interacting with multiple databases. That's what you are doing here. In order to establish the connection, you must set up `DATABASE_ROUTERS` for all of your apps’ models.
**exampe for DBRouter**

```
class AuthRouter:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return 'auth_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write auth models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return 'auth_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the auth app is involved.
        """
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'auth' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'auth':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'auth_db'
        database.
        """
        if app_label == 'auth':
            return db == 'auth_db'
        return None
```

and in your `settings.py`, `DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.AuthRouter']`
You can find more details and info from  [django's official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/).

Answer (score 1):

Django try to find a table `<app_name>_<model_name>` which matching to its model, but you can add this `Meta` class below to `Item` class to change how Django works (or change your table name to `project_items`):

```
class Item(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'items'
```

Comment: The generated `app/models.py` is pretty similar to yours. I have updated my question to reflect this.